# Friend function scope and point of declaration

Tags: c++, friend

I've written the simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A
{
    friend void foo() { printf("asd\n"); }
};

int main()
{
    A::foo();//fail, foo is not a member of A
}
```

How can I invoke this friend function defined inside the class body? Also I would like to know what is the point of declaration and scope of friend function.

Comment: `friend` does not work that way! Please read the docs. Did you actually want `static`, instead?

Comment: Did you mean `static void foo() {`?

Comment: @Rook Please give me a refer to the standard to read.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv You've presumably read what `friend` is for, before you added it to your program. What were you expecting to happen here?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, I'm trying to understand friend function working principle. Their scope and point of declaration.

Comment: (as an aside, I'm slightly surprised that the above code compiles. why is a function body allowed after a friend function prototype declaration?)

Comment: @Rook See the function-definition syntax 8.4.1. Decl-specifier and function body are allowed here. friend is decl-specifier 7.1/1.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv and yet it clearly doesn't work. But that's irrelevant to my question, which I'll ask again: you've presumably read what friend is for, before you added it to your program. What were you expecting to happen here?

Comment: @Rook I expected nothing. I'm just trying to understand what scope of the foo.

Comment: So that sounds a lot like you're guessing at what `friend` does! `friend` states a function or method that is defined outside the class is able to access private members inside the class. A `friend` function that already belonged to the class makes no sense... member functions can already see all their class' private state. See πάντα ῥεῖ's answer below for an example of useage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all to declare a friend function do

```
class A
{
    friend void foo();
};
```

and define the function outside of the class

```
void foo { printf("asd\n"); }
```

It will be called as any other normal function

```
int main() {
    foo();
}
```

The point is, that the `friend` declaration in class `A` allows `foo()` access to any internal (`private` or `protected`) members of this class.

To additionally clarify: It is possible to define the function body at the point of the friend declaration, but it's still to be called as shown.